# drawing and animating in android

Tags: android, graphics, animation

first off, this is more of a question about animating than a specific problem coding.  i need to fill in the broad strokes left by the research i've been doing.

what i'm trying to do:

the activity should load with only the a togglebutton visible.  when the button is touched, a png will be animated to a certain position relative to the togglebutton.  also, another button will slide in from off screen and slide off if/when the togglebutton is pressed again.

what i can't figure out:

i can draw an image, but only via xml.  creating an imageview and setting the background programmatically does nothing.

when i draw from xml, i can't move the image when the togglebutton is pressed like i want to.  when i call getPositionOnScreen() i get a null pointer, even though the complier can see i'm referring to the imageview described in both xml and in code.

i'm calling getPositionOnScreen because via xml, i have the image positioned behind the togglebutton so that it's not visible until the button has been pressed and the image starts moving.  the idea is that with different screen sizes i won't know exactly where the view is until runtime.  getPostionOnScreen allows me to get the coordinates of the imageview so i know where it has been positioned.  when i have a start position, can tell it to "move up" on the screen from behind the togglebutton by simply adding to x or y until it's where i want.

this is the code to draw the image (inserted in the onCreate method).

```
image= (ImageView) new ImageView(this);
  image.setImageResource(R.drawable.pic);
```

this is the code i'm using to animate.  when the button is clicked, it calls this method on the view from the listener.

```
private void activate(){

  int loc[] = new int [2];
  image.getLocationOnScreen(loc);
  int fromXDelta = loc[0];
     int fromYDelta = loc[1];
  int toYDelta = fromYDelta;
     int toXDelta = fromXDelta - 30;

  TranslateAnimation translateAnimation = new TranslateAnimation
  (-fromXDelta, -toXDelta, -fromYDelta, -toYDelta);
     translateAnimation.setDuration(500);
     translateAnimation.setFillEnabled(true);

     image.startAnimation(translateAnimation);

 }
```

i'm well aware that this is horribly wrong and won't work.  what i need to understand is why.  any help would be very welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright the first point. If you are creating a new `ImageView` object that way (by using `new`) you don't have to cast it to 'ImageView`manually as it already is a fresh'n new`ImageView`.

Now to make you understand why your `ImageView` wasn't displayed when declaring it the way you initially tired (i.e. by creating a new object) because you most likely had the `setContentView()` methods parameter in your `onCreate()` method set to `R.layout.main` (your main.xml file containing your layout). Now that simply won't work as Android won't know what you are trying to do with the `ImageView` you've created as you never use it. Yo could either define a `ViewGroup` (LinearLayout, AbsoluteLayout, etc.) in Java by code and assign all your widgets (ImageView, ToggleButton, etc.) to them and then set it as the parameter of `setContentView()` to get them displayed or you can go the easier way and define all you need in your XML file containing your layout like I did.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/trigger"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textOn="Active"
        android:textOff="Stopped"
        android:checked="false"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/trigger"
        android:visibility="invisible"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Now in Java you just have to get the references (or pointers) to your widgets right so you can use them for all kinds of nasty stuff like animating them.

Here is my Java code.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.animation.TranslateAnimation;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.ToggleButton;

public class VeryCoolAnimation extends Activity {

    ImageView image = null;
    ToggleButton trigger = null;
    Context ctx = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        ctx = getApplicationContext();

        trigger = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.trigger);
        image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);

        image.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon);

        trigger.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                    boolean isChecked) {
                if(isChecked) {
                    animate();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void animate() {
        int loc[] = new int[2];
        image.getLocationOnScreen(loc);
        // Just used to print out the images position
        Toast.makeText(ctx, "Position on screen: x = " + loc[0] + " y = " + loc[1], 5000).show();
        int fromXDelta = loc[0];
        int fromYDelta = loc[1];
            int toYDelta = fromYDelta + 50;
        int toXDelta = fromXDelta + 80;

        TranslateAnimation translateAnimation = new TranslateAnimation(
                fromXDelta, toXDelta, fromYDelta, toYDelta);
        translateAnimation.setDuration(800);
        translateAnimation.setFillEnabled(true);

        image.startAnimation(translateAnimation);
        image.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
}
```

I'm not entirely sure that this is the effect you were aiming for but you can of course adjust it to suit your needs as you have a fully functional piece of code.

Good luck.

Comment: octavian, i see from your example that a big mistake i was making was indeed in creating the button.  i wasn't calling findViewById and so the compiler didn't know i was trying to associate what was described in the xml with what was described in the java.  one issue i have is that when i plug in the code, i don't see anything during the animation process.  i see the image when the activity loads but it dissapears only to reappear in the same exact place when the animation finishes.

Comment: another question i have (though perhaps it should be posted as a different question) is about context.  i've read about the class on google's site but can't find a definition i understand.  i can't find any tutorials or articles that take the time to explain what exactly it is and what function it performs.  i sort of understand it but i know i have definite work to do in that area.  can you recommend a newb friendly source of info on that?

Comment: @strangeInAStrangerLand: The invisible image might be due to me setting its visibility to invisible by default and then when the animation is done I set it to invisible again with `image.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)`. Regarding the context. It holds a reference to your application or main activity class. One useful thing it does it as you can see to tell the Toast to appear in the applications context. I recommend getting a hold of Mark Murphy's books at http://commonsware.com.

Comment: I've actually read a couple of his books.  They're what got me started in android.  There's a lot in them that i haven't worked up to yet but I refer to beginning android 2.0 daily.  I figured out what was causing the vanishing image.  I had altered what you wrote and was moving the view off screen.  Thanks for all your help, getting an animation to work was a big step for me.